# Does CloudSim have to use AWS?

Tags: cloudsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If I have a cluster of computers that are already setup to run as a Cloud, can I use CloudSim on that cluster?  Or is there any plans to release CloudSim to support any cluster of computers?

If it is possible, what do I have to install to run CloudSim and Gazebo over my own cluster?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2036/does-cloudsim-have-to-use-aws?/) by [astaranowicz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/149/astaranowicz/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 51 on 2013-03-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In principle, CloudSim can run atop a variety of cloud computing providers.  The current implementation is AWS EC2-specific through its reliance on the [boto library](https://github.com/boto/boto).  We started with EC2 and boto because of their extensive and, for the most part, reliable set of features.

We plan to generalize CloudSim to run on other cloud computing systems, perhaps through the use of [libcloud](http://libcloud.apache.org/), which provides a common abstraction layer.  Doing so may require refactoring to, for example, not rely on AWS's [Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/).

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Max Pfingsthorn](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/103/max-pfingsthorn/) on 2013-08-30**:
What about using a (somewhat) AWS-compatible cloud manager, like Cloudstack (http://cloudstack.apache.org/)? Can you list the AWS features required for CloudSim right now?

**Comment by [Carlos Agüero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/280/carlos-ag%C3%BCero/) on 2013-08-30**:
We are finishing the OpenStack support for CloudSim. If you have your own cloud based on OpenStack, you should be able to use CloudSim and launch constellations with gazebo+ros within your cluster. Stay tuned!